# Using Protractor with Angular2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, angular

I have a little project in angular2 that I'm trying to write some simple tests for using protractor..

I am using a ngFor to loop round a list of 'foos' and display them on the page (simple enough).

Then I want my test to get the text of the 1st one and check to see if it's 'bar':

```
element.all(by.repeater('foo of foos')).get(1).then(function(x){
  expect(x.getText()).toEqual('bar');
});
```

But when I run my test I get:

> Failed: element.all(...).get(...).then is not a function

Any idea what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that:

- `element.all(by.repeater('foo of foos')).get(1)` is an `ElementFinder`
- you cannot resolve `ElementFinder` with `then()` ([breaking change in Protractor 2.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-2))

Instead, do:

```
var elm = element.all(by.repeater('foo of foos')).get(1);
expect(elm.getText()).toEqual('bar');
```

Comment: awesome that has fixed that, I'm no longer getting that error thanks :).

Comment: That doesn't work by me with Angular 5.1.0, protractor 5.2.2