# Protractor - ngFor loop

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor

I'm using latest Angular and latest Protractor version and I'm wondering how to work with ngFor loop in my tests.

In past in my AngularJS app it was simple. I just used something like `by.repeater` and magic was done behind.

However now in Angular 4 APP I'm not that lucky.
Based on this [ticket](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3205) it is not supported yet. At another hand I saw a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271473/using-protractor-with-angular2#_=_) ticket when somone is already working with it.

Anyway my HTML is:

```
<div *ngFor="let org of userOrgList; count as count">
   <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-12" type="submit"  (click)="selectOrg(org.id)">{{org.name}}</button>
</div>
```

And my test looks like:

```
var organizations = element.all(by.repeater('org of userOrgList'));

it('should have an org with specific name', function() {
    expect(organizations.get(0).getText()).toEqual('myOrgName');
});
```

And I get an error:

> Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but
>   there are only 0 elements that match locator by.rep eater("let org of
>   userOrgList; count as count")

**My question is:**
How to work with ngFor inside my protractor test

Comment: Ran into the same issue, and found out there is an open issue to support `*ngFor` for Angular 2+ https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3205

Comment: yea mate, it's the same ticket I link in my question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution I found that works for me but still not as clean as it was with repeater

```
// HTML FILE: Added id to DIV 
<div *ngFor="let org of userOrgList; count as count" id="organizations">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-xs-12" type="submit"  (click)="selectOrg(org.id)">{{org.name}}</button>
</div>

//TEST FILE:
var organizations = element.all(by.id('organizations')).all(by.css('button'));
var firstOrg = organizations.get(0);
it('should have an org with specific name', function() {
    expect(firstOrg.getText()).toEqual('Name you expect');
});
```

With a standard table repeater it may looks like:

```
var data = element.all(by.css('table[name='' + TableName + '']')).all(by.css('tr td'));
expect(data.get(0).getText()).toEqual('0');
```